# Xdebug Tailored info page not giving good info

Tags: php, windows-7, xdebug, apache2.2

Have Apache2.2, PHP 5.4(VC9) 32 bit installed and working. Trying to install xdebug but fails with error "Failed loading c:\program files (x86)\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.20RC1-5.4-vc9.dll". File name and path are correct. Tried using Xdebug custom install wizard but does not return any useful information, ie version to download, path all empty.

```
I installed php_xdebug-2.2.0RC1-5.4-vc9.dll to php extension folder.
```

**Relevant php ini lines:**

```
zend_extension = "c:\program files (x86)\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.20RC1-5.4-vc9.dll"


xdebug.remote_enable=On

xdebug.remote_autostart=On

xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp

xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1

xdebug.remote_port=9000

xdebug.remote_mode=req
```

**Relevant Apache config settings:**

```
PHPIniDir "C:/program files (x86)/php"


LoadModule php5_module "c:/program files (x86)/php/php5apache2_2.dll"
```

**Information returned from Xdebug tailored installation page:**

```
Xdebug installed: no

Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler

Windows: yes - Compiler: MS VC9 - Architecture: x86

Zend Server: no

PHP Version: 5.4.0

Zend API nr: 220100525

PHP API nr: 20100525

Debug Build: no

Thread Safe Build: yes

Configuration File Path: C:\windows

Configuration File: C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php.ini
```

Extensions directory:

Instructions

```
Download
Move the downloaded file to
Edit C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php.ini and add the line
zend_extension = \
Restart the webserver
```

I tried to post my phpinfo but stack kept saying I had improperly formatted code - even when I put pre code /code /pre blocks around the whole thing. So here is the important stuff:

PHP Version 5.4.0

System  Windows NT TTS-DAMON 6.1 build 7601 (Windows 7 Home Premium Edition Service Pack 1) i586
Build Date  Feb 29 2012 19:20:16
Compiler    MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008)
Architecture    x86
Configure Command   cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--disable-isapi" "--enable-debug-pack" "--disable-nsapi" "--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql" "--without-pi3web" "--with-pdo-oci=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-11g=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient11\sdk,shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet" "--with-mcrypt=static" "--disable-static-analyze" "--with-pgo"
Server API  Apache 2.0 Handler
Virtual Directory Support   enabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   C:\windows
Loaded Configuration File   C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files     (none)
Additional .ini files parsed    (none)
PHP API     20100412
PHP Extension   20100525
Zend Extension  220100525
Zend Extension Build    API220100525,TS,VC9
PHP Extension Build     API20100525,TS,VC9
Debug Build     no
Thread Safety   enabled
Zend Signal Handling    disabled
Zend Memory Manager     enabled
Zend Multibyte Support  provided by mbstring
IPv6 Support    enabled
DTrace Support  disabled
Registered PHP Streams  php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, zip, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, phar
Registered Stream Socket Transports tcp, udp
Registered Stream Filters   convert.iconv.*, mcrypt.*, mdecrypt.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk, zlib.*, bzip2.*

Zend logo This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies

**Never Mind**

For anyone reading this I found my own answer. PHP does not like the default name of the xdebug file. I just renamed it php_xdebug.dll and all worked well.

Comment: That is weird, as PHP just doesn't care about it. I've always used the original filename that the Xdebug download provided. Perhaps just a  case of not having picked up the new configuration...

Answer (score 1):

Even though you got this fixed, this may explain why it wasn't working before. It looks like you were missing a . after the second 2 in the version number on the file name. In the php.ini, it should be:

```
zend_extension = "c:\program files (x86)\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.0RC1-5.4-vc9.dll"
```